# High Sierra permissions failing to modify recursively via Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, high-sierra, permission

Trying to change permissions via Terminal:

```
$~ sudo chmod -r 777 [DIRECTORY LOCATION HERE]
```

Before it can start diving into the subfolders, it comes back with:

`chmod: 777: No such file or directory`.

Looking at the files, the folder is now "Write-Only (Dropbox)" across the board.

Attempting to adjust batch permissions via Get Info panel does not recursively apply even when directed to do so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The letter used in the terminal command must be a capital "R", not a lower-case "r".

e.g. use:

```
    sudo chmod -R 777 [dir]
```

not:

```
    sudo chmod -r 777 [dir]
```

Comment: Additional explanation: `chmod -r` means "remove read access". That's why it came out as "Write-Only (Dropbox)".

Comment: I'd REALLY question someone who thought a recursive '777' was something that should be combined with sudo.